# Get username in Django login_required decorator

Tags: django, logging, decorator

In my django **views.py**, there are **75 functions** and for every function, i am using **@login_required** decorator and I want to **capture the username** when someone hits corresponding function.

I am able to get that by using **request.user.username** but I have to write this line in all 75 functions which is redundant... Is there a way to get/print username in @login_required decorator itself by default so that I can skip writing the same line in all the functions.

Following is the snippet for @login_required decorator.

```
def login_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in, redirecting
    to the log-in page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

**Note** :- By capture, I mean I want to do **logger.info(request.user.username)** or get username by other means

Comment: What do you mean with `capture`?

Comment: @Vincent I mean i want to do logger.info(request.user.username)

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways to go about this that immediately stand out..

You could write your own custom decorator:

```
def custom_login_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in, redirecting
    to the log-in page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if request.user.username: #probably better ways to write this
        logger.info(request.user.username)
    elif function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

You could use `CBV`s and `Mixin`s (one of my favorite ways to write reusable code) and override the [LoginRequiredMixin](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.contrib.auth.mixins/LoginRequiredMixin/)'s `dispatch()` method (I believe this is the best method to override):

```
class LoginRequiredMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            logger.info(request.user.username)
        else: 
            pass
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Youll have to verify if this code is written correctly. I wrote it quickly...

Also, a third way would to be to write [a custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware), which is probably the best option of all 3.